# $pull multiple objects within a document - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f7ae123227916c02f1ce6"),
    "items" : [     {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f89d63a983002e4562fb2"),
            "item_id" : "123",
            "upc" : "ean"

        },
                {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f89d63a983002e4562fb2"),
            "item_id" : "456",
            "upc" : "ean",

        },
            {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f89d63a983002e4562fb2"),
            "item_id" : "242",
            "upc" : "ean",

        } ]
}
```

I want to delete multiple object within an items array. The query I am using is..

```
        db.collection.update({}, {$pull: {items: {item_id: {$in: ["123", "456"] }} } } )
```

I checked this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709923/mongodb-pull-multiple-objects-from-an-array), which is same as mine. But it didn't work for me.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issue with your query, Since you've used [.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html), it would've updated first found document from result of filter : `{'items.item_id': {$in: ["123", "456"] }}`, So might have just updated one document out of many matching that filter criteria - which you probably might have missed to observe, Please print the output of that query. As you've nothing mentioned in filter `{}` - So in case if you wanted to update all documents that match with filter passed in update then use [.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) or pass `{multi : true}` as an option to same `.update()`.

**Example :**

```
db.collection.update({}, {$pull: {items: {item_id: {$in: ["123", "456"] }}}}, {multi: true})
```

*(Or)*

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$pull: {items: {item_id: {$in: ["123", "456"] }}}})
```

Comment: Hi Srinivas, I was trying it in a new collection which has only one document. Also I did try with the filter, but got no success.

Comment: @ravi : what are you getting with this `db.collection.find({ 'items.item_id': { $in: ["123", "456"] } })` 
? As I've mentioned in my first comment did you check are you getting connected to right DB & correct collection ?

Comment: I am connecting to the right collection and the right db. Sorry for late reply, was travelling. @whoami

Comment: @ravi : Did you try executing same query in any client ? robot3T or mongo compass ?