# How to pull a range of objects from an array of objects and re-insert them at a new position in the array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Desired Behaviour**

`Pull` a range of objects from an array of objects and `push` them back to the array at a new index.

For example, pull objects from the array where their index is between 0 and 2, and push them back to the array at position 6.

For reference, in jQuery, the desired behaviour can be achieved with:

```js
if (before_or_after === "before") {
    $("li").eq(new_position).before($("li").slice(range_start, range_end + 1));
} else if (before_or_after === "after") {
    $("li").eq(new_position).after($("li").slice(range_start, range_end + 1));
}
```

[jsFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/aw1mztg7)

**Schema**

```js
{
    "_id": ObjectId("*********"),
    "title": "title text",
    "description": "description text",
    "statements": [
    {
        "text": "string",
        "id": "********"
    },
    {
        "text": "string",
        "id": "********"
    },
    {
        "text": "string",
        "id": "********"
    },
    {
        "text": "string",
        "id": "********"
    },
    {
        "text": "string",
        "id": "********"
    }]
}
```

**What I've Tried**

I am able to reposition a *single* object in an array of objects with the code below.

It uses `pull` to remove the object from the array and `push` to add it back to the array at a new position.

In order to do the same for a *range of objects*, I think I just need to modify the `$pull` and `$push` variables but:

- I can't figure out how to use `$slice` in this context, either [as a projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice) or [an aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice), in a `$pull` operation
- Because I can't figure out the first bit, I don't know how to attempt the second bit - the `$push` operation

```js
// define the topic_id to search for  
var topic_id = request_body.topic_id;

// make it usable as a search query  
var o_id = new ObjectID(topic_id);

// define the statement_id to search for   
var statement_id = request_body.statement_id;

// define new position
var new_position = Number(request_body.new_position);

// define old position
var old_position = Number(request_body.old_position);

// define before or after (this will be relevant later)
// var before_or_after = request_body.before_or_after;

// define the filter 
var filter = { _id: o_id };

// define the pull update - to remove the object from the array of objects  
var pull_update = {
    $pull: {
        statements: { id: statement_id }  // <----- how do i pull a range of objects here  
    }
};

// define the projection so that only the 'statements' array is returned
var options = { projection: { statements: 1 } };

try {
    // perform the pull update  
    var topic = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, pull_update, options);

    // get the returned statement object so that it can be inserted at the desired index
    var returned_statement = topic.value.statements[old_position];

    // define the push update - to add the object back to the array at the desired position
    var push_update = {
        $push: {
            statements: {
                $each: [returned_statement],
                $position: new_position
            }
        }     // <----- how do i push the range of objects back into the array here  
    };

    // perform the push update  
    var topic = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, push_update);

}
```

**Environments**

```
##### local
  
$  mongod --version
db version v4.0.3

$  npm view mongodb version
3.5.9

$ node -v
v10.16.3

$ systeminfo
OS Name:        Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:     10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363

##### production
  
$ mongod --version
db version v3.6.3

$ npm view mongodb version
3.5.9

$ node -v
v8.11.4

RedHat OpenShift Online, Linux
```

**Edit**

Gradually, figuring out parts of the problem, I think:

Using [the example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21952273), the following returns objects from array with index `0 - 2` (ie 3 objects):

```js
db.topics.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": ObjectId("********") } },
    { "$project": { "statements": { "$slice": ["$statements", 0, 3] }, _id: 0 } }
])
```

Not sure how to use that in a `pull` yet...

I also looked into [using `$in`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710195) (even though i would prefer to just grab a *range* of objects than have to specify each object's id), but realised it does not preserve the order of the array values provided in the results returned:

[Does MongoDB's $in clause guarantee order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22797768/does-mongodbs-in-clause-guarantee-order)

Here is one solution to re-ordering results from `$in` in Node:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34751295

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to MongoDB v4.2? If so you can perform the update in one operation, using [updates with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). Otherwise I *think* you'll have to get the whole document and process it in node.js and update with the modified array.

Comment: i'm waiting to hear back on whether 4.0 and then 4.2 is available in production server so i can start the upgrade path from 3.6.3, bit concerned there may be compatibility bugs introduced from the upgrade, but looks like its the only option.

Comment: update: found out that OpenShift MongoDB images only go up to `v3.6.3`.  if anyone can provide a solid, best-practise, solution to achieve the desired behaviour, regardless of MongoDB version constraints, that would be great - i still need to know how it can be achieved and will sort out the MongoDB versions later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example with mongo 3.5

```js
const mongo = require('mongodb')

;(async function (params) {
  const client = await mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017')

  const coll = client.db('test').collection('test')

  const from0to99 = Array(100).fill('0').map((_, i) => String(i))
  const from5To28 = Array(24).fill('0').map((_, i) => String(i + 5))

  const insert = { statements: from0to99.map(_ => ({ id: _ })) }
  await coll.insertOne(insert)

  const all100ElementsRead = await coll.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: insert._id },
    {
      $pull: {
        statements: {
          id: { $in: from5To28 }
        }
      }
    },
    { returnOriginal: true }
  )
  /**
   * It shows the object with the desired _id BEFORE doing the $pull
   * You can process all the old elements as you wish
   */
  console.log(all100ElementsRead.value.statements)

  // I use the object read from the database to push back
  // since I know the $in condition, I must filter the array returned
  const pushBack = all100ElementsRead.value.statements.filter(_ => from5To28.includes(_.id))

  // push back the 5-28 range at position 72
  const pushed = await coll.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: insert._id },
    {
      $push: {
        statements: {
          $each: pushBack,
          $position: 72 // 0-indexed
        }
      }
    },
    { returnOriginal: false }
  )
  console.log(pushed.value.statements) // show all the 100 elements

  client.close()
})()
```

[This old issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2016) helped

Comment: if i am reading this correctly, 1)  it uses `$in` to do the initial `$pull` - as mentioned in OP, this doesn't preserve the order of the elements provided in `$in` so it is no good for pulling the elements from the array and preserving their order so that they can be pushed back into the array at a new position  2)  the `$push` seems to be given new values (not the values originally pulled), so it doesn't seem to fulfil the desired behaviour - ie pull a range of values from an array and re-insert them at a different index. apologies if i am misreading it.

Comment: I have simplified the code in order to be more readable. 
1) since you read the value before change it, the order you get will be the same 2) so don't you want to push the elements ad the and or beginning but `id: five` at position 3 and `id: six` at position 1 for example?

Comment: you are using $in to pull objects from an array, the order you define using $in is not necessarily the order they will come back in.   therefore, if you say ‘x equals the result of remove 1,2,3’ , x may equal 3,1,2.  and when you insert x back into the array all the order is wrong.  i don’t understand what you mean by ‘since you read the value before change it, the order you get will be the same’.  using your example, how do you pull ‘two’ and ‘three’, and put them back in the array after ‘four’?  (taking into account, real scenario could be like ‘move objects  5 - 28 to position 72)

Comment: Thanks to `returnOriginal: true` you will get the original data, give me a bit to update the response

Comment: @user1063287 updated. Notice that you may evaluate `$position` as you want

Answer (score -1):

if you want "desired behavior" when mutating arrays ,
you add these to checklist:

- array.length atleast==7 if you want to add ,splice at 6
- creates a new array if u use concat
- mutates orignal if used array.push or splice or a[a.length]='apple'

USE slice() to select between incex1 to index2.

or run a native for loop to select few elements of array or

apply a array.filter() finction.

once you select your elements which needed to be manupulated you mentioned you want to add it to end. so this is the method below.
**about adding elements at end:**

CONCAT EXAMPLE

```
const original = ['']; //const does not mean its immutable just that it cant be reassigned
let newArray;

newArray = original.concat('');
newArray = [...original, ''];

// Result
newArray; // ['', '']
original; // ['']
```

SPLICE EXAMPLE:

```
const zoo = ['', ''];

zoo.splice(
  zoo.length, // We want add at the END of our array
  0, // We do NOT want to remove any item
  '', '', '', // These are the items we want to add
);

console.log(zoo); // ['', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: im talking about the nodejs part assuming you first make a query then execute it to fetch data from mongoDB. if you want a mongo specific answer ill learn it and update the answer later...